# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to nodejs. I've a MEAN stack project `employee`, `department` and `user roles` models. While creating the `employee` i'm checking for `department` and `userrole`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Employee = require('../models/employee');
const UserRoles = require('../models/userRole');
const Department = require('../models/department');
const _ = require('lodash');

exports.create_employee = (req, res, next) => {

    Department.findById(req.body.deptID)
        .then( dept => {
            if( !dept ) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Department not found'
                });
            }
            return UserRoles.findById(req.body.userRoleID)
                .then( role => {
                    if( !role ) {
                        return res.status(404).json({
                            message: 'User role not found'
                        });
                    }
                    const employee = new Employee({
                        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                        name: req.body.name,
                        designation: req.body.designation,
                        doj: req.body.doj,
                        dob: req.body.dob,
                        bloodGroup: req.body.bloodGroup,
                        deptID: req.body.deptID,
                        userRoleID: req.body.userRoleID,
                        empCode: req.body.empCode
                    });
                    return employee.save();
                })
        })
        .then(result => {
            let ob = _.omit(result, ['__v']);
            res.status(201).json({
                createdEmployee: ob
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Internal Server Error'
            });
        });
};
```

When i try to create an employee with `deptID` and `userRoleID` which are not present in response am getting correct response as `not found`. But in terminal am getting below error

[image]

I think am doing some wrong return please correct me!!

Comment: Hint. You're chaining promises and returning values where you probably should be throwing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Response is already sent and again a response is being sent by MongoDB callback (UserRole). Your **Department.findById** and **UserRoles.findById** queries are independent to each other so here Promise chaining not required.

***Very well written answer on Response header can be found here...***

> [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

**You can try this modified code.**

```
exports.create_employee = async (req, res, next) => {
 try {
    let dept = await Department.findById(req.body.deptID);
    if (!dept) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Department not found'
        });
    }
    let role = await UserRoles.findById(req.body.userRoleID);
    if (!role) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'User role not found'
        });
    }
    // onward code will execute only when role and dept exists.
    const employee = new Employee({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        designation: req.body.designation,
        doj: req.body.doj,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        bloodGroup: req.body.bloodGroup,
        deptID: req.body.deptID,
        userRoleID: req.body.userRoleID,
        empCode: req.body.empCode
    });
    const result = await employee.save();

    let ob = _.omit(result, ['__v']);
    res.status(201).json({
        createdEmployee: ob
    });

} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Internal Server Error'
    });
}};
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can't set headers after they are sent

You are replying to the request more than once. Find out which code paths get executed that cause this and fix them.

You should only `res.status()...` once for every request.